# Send query gps from android to mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, gps

I make an simple android application. when user click send it's send user gps location to mysql. 
this is my android source code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
Button insert=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(gps.canGetLocation()){   
             lat = (float) gps.getLatitude();
             lng = (float) gps.getLatitude();
             lat2= Float.toString(lat);
             lng2= Float.toString(lng);


            insert();

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success insert - \nLat: " + lat2 + "\nLong: " + lng2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
        }else{
            // can't get location
            // GPS or Network is not enabled
            // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }
        }});
}

public void insert() {
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat2", lat2));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng2", lng2));

    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.56.1/MUF_Surabaya/Rute/insert_android.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
        Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
    }

    try {
        JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
        code = (json_data.getInt("code"));

        if (code == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserted Successfully",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, Try Again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
    }
}

}
```

this is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnShowLocation"
    android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
    android:padding="11dp"
    android:text="Send" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and my php source code to catch the gps

```
<?php
$host='127.0.0.1';
$uname='root';
$pwd='';
$db="test";

$con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");

$lat2=(isset($_REQUEST['lat']) ? $_REQUEST['lat'] : '');
$lng2=(isset($_REQUEST['lng']) ? $_REQUEST['lng'] : '');


//$lat2=$_REQUEST['lat'];
//$lng2=$_REQUEST['lng'];

var_dump($lat2);



$flag['code']=0;

if($r=mysql_query("insert into markers_awal values('','$lat2','$lng2') ",$con))
{
    $flag['code']=1;
    echo"hi";
}

print(json_encode($flag));
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

this code no error, but in my sql show that lat 0 , lng 0

Comment: does your lat and long have values before you send them??

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin yes there is

Comment: I think your lat and long value is 0, have you checked that ?

Comment: @pratik I`v been check it and the value is not null

Comment: it may be not null but may be it is 0 as per me

Comment: @user3233176 I think you need to get Latitude and Longitude with some other way.

Comment: @user3233176 I have code to get lat and Long properly, in that you will get lat,long data perfectly, so after that you can insert it

Comment: @pratik the toats show my lat and long

Comment: Try this two lines :  lat2= String.valueOf(lat);
             lng2= String.valueOf(lng);

Comment: @pratik thnk you so much but it doesn't save in mysql

Comment: ooopss, can you send me your source code, let me check in my editor, if u dnt mind?

Comment: I think you doing silly mistake there. In NameValuePair you sending data named "lat2" and "lng2" and php side you save with the name "lat" and "lng", so please take a look into it.

Comment: @pratik ye you are right thnk you so much my "lat2" and "lng2" and php side i save with the name "lat" and "lng"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$lat2=(isset($_REQUEST['lat']) ? $_REQUEST['lat'] : '');
$lng2=(isset($_REQUEST['lng']) ? $_REQUEST['lng'] : '');
```

In above 2 lines you getting key wrong, you passed lat2 and lng2 from android side, so you must need to get lat2 and lng2 here then only you will get perfect values.